# How to render external template on button click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have the following markup:

```
<main ng-controller="MainController">
    <article id="story-container"></article>
    <button ng-click="newSection()">+ Add Section</button>
 </main>
```

I need to compile and append the following template inside article element on button click.

```
<script  id="newSectionTmpl" type="text/ng-template">
    <section>Hello, {{name}}!</section>
</script>
```

I have tried something like this, but not sure if this is a good approach:

```
app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app
  .controller('MainController',['$scope', '$compile', function($scope, $compile) {
    $scope.name = "Denis";
    $scope.newSection = function() {
      var tmpl = $('#newSectionTmpl').html();
      var $el = $('#story-container');
      console.log(tmpl);
      var html = $compile(tmpl)($scope);
      $el.append(tmpl);
    }
  }                                                                
]);
```

Also, how can I load my template from external file?
Here is the link to jsBin: [http://jsbin.com/zuyicewexahi/5/edit?html,js,output](http://jsbin.com/zuyicewexahi/latest)

Comment: To load template from external file, use jquery's load() function. This is very useful function to load external file. For more info, check this link: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thanks! I'm wondering if there is an angular way of doing it...

Comment: use $templateCache instead of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try **ng-include** directive
[ng-include documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<div class="modal-header">
<form  ng-include src="'/src/sample.html'"></form>
</div>
```

sample.html is an external file which will load into your current html using ng-include directive

Comment: Hi, Jan! It will render sample.html during compile stage. How do I render sample.html on button click and append it to a particular element?

Answer (score 0):

Angular is awesome, you won't be needing most of the jquery there. See plunkr below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/yqhnQyR4NrFvnUBn7ite?p=preview

You need to set name to 'Noypi' ... 'just kidding...'

```
app.controller('MainController',['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Noypi";
    $scope.content = "";

}]);
```

html...

```
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <button ng-click="content = 'newSectionTmpl'">+ Add Section</button>
    <div  ng-include src="content"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Great idea! But it will append template only once. What if I want n templates to render?

Comment: that's another question. accept this answer, create a plunkr for the new question, i'll show you how.